# Create a list of strings

Tags: qt

I am going to create a list of string, for example, `["a", "10", "p20", ...]`. Which way is more efficient, using `string`, `vector`, `QVector`, `QLinkedList` or others?

Comment: Use QStringList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficiency depends on how you're going to use them. For instance, if you're inserting into the middle, QStringList (which is QList ) handles insertions very well. If you know the exact size up front and it isn't going to change, then QVector might be a better choice. Read up on the various possibilities and then use the one that's appropriate for your needs.

The QVector documentation provides a nice guideline for comparing the different Qt-based possibilities.